# Is it possible to get and show details from a poi with Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to get and show the details (from image 2) directly in the map (picture 1) without that the user must click the link and open a new page?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add a "click" listener to the `google.maps.Map()` object to listen for clicks on the POIs. If one is clicked, you can suppress the default behavior by calling `event.stop()`. The result of the click will be a lat/lng and a Place ID.

Then, you can use the [`google.maps.places.PlacesService()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/places-service#PlacesService) to get the details from that Place ID as a [`google.maps.places.PlacesResult()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/places-service#PlaceResult), which contains much of the information on the maps.google.com place page. This information can be used to display in a `google.maps.InfoWindow()`

Here is a [very simple proof of concept JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gifirucepo/edit?html,output). Do note that the InfoWindow is very simple and unformatted, and some details will not always be present in the PlacesResult object, but with some nice CSS and data checks, you can make a very rich and detailed InfoWindow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 37.421959, lng: -122.084269},
          zoom: 14
        });

        var placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        map.addListener('click', function(event) {
            if (event.placeId) {
              event.stop();
              placesService.getDetails({placeId: event.placeId}, function(place, status) {
                  var content = '<div>'+
                    '<div >'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<h1 class="firstHeading">' + place.name + '</h1>'+
                    '<div">'+
                    '<p>' + place.formatted_address + '</p>'+
                    '<p>' + place.formatted_phone_number + '</p>'+
                    '<p><a href="' + place.website + '">' + place.website + '</a></p>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < place.photos.length; i++) {
                      content += '<img src="' + place.photos[i].getUrl({maxHeight: 50}) + '">';
                    }
                    content += '</div></div>';

                  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                      maxWidth: 300,
                      content: content,
                      position: event.latLng
                  });
                  infoWindow.open(map);
              });
            }
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&libraries=places&key=YOUR_KEY"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```